# Detect and display IE8 to then display an existing IE8 css style sheet with MVC 3 Razor

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-3, cross-browser

I'm converting a web forms application and in a code behind I see where a guy checked for IE8 browser, then displays that IE8 CSS.  If I had the time I would figure out what the differences are, but for now I'm thinking that I would just like a nice clean approach in mvc 3 razor to  1. check for which browser is used ( namely IE8 ) and then display the appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional tag.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <!-- include your ie8 stylesheet here -->
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: @Craig

If I have a razor page with this                                                                      @section Styles {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/default.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
}
Where is a good place for your tag?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't say the best place, but you can use it in your section or your layout. It's standard html, nothing asp.net or mvc specific.

Comment: You're welcome. If that does it for you, please click the check to mark this as the answer. :)

Comment: Looking into these conditional statements, can there be an 'else' ?

Comment: You can't do else but you can add a second conditional tag with a NOT operator. <!--[if !IE 8]> <![endif]-->

Comment: For Firefox to work, I had to do this FYI 
"Downlevel-revealed Conditional Comments"
  
    `<![if !IE]>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/home.css")" 
    rel="stylesheet"  />
    <![endif]--> 
    `

Comment: Ok, IE will not render html at all with the above , thus now I'm getting this to finally work in IE8 and FF3.6  .... 
    `<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/home.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--<![endif]-->`